# Finding all complex roots of this equation

Tags: analysis, complex-numbers

So i have this equation:

$z^5-4z^4+11z^3+12z^2-42z+52=0 \text{ for }z\in\Bbb{C}$

One root is: $z=1+i$
That gives us also the 2nd root. $z=1-i$
But i am stuck with how to get other 3.
I thought i could divide the equation with those two but i don't know how.
Or maybe it would be possible with horner's algorithm,which i also am not sure how tio use in this situation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the [polynomial remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem)?

Comment: How can apply it here though?

Comment: By dividing the polynomial by $(z - 1 - i)(z - 1 + i)$.

Comment: Hint: $(z-1-i)(z-1+i) = z^2-2z+2$; next, use long division.

Comment: If $z=1\pm i$ are roots, then divide the expression by the product (to be developed) of the two roots $(z-1-i)\times (z-1+i)= ???$

Comment: That could  work.

Comment: It is always the same principle : long division ! Cheers

Comment: You want some wine with that. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tip: $(z-1-i)(z-1+i)=z^2-2z+2$

Then, long division gives:$$\frac{z^5−4z^4+11z^3+12z^2−42z+52}{z^2-2z+2} = z^3-2 z^2+5 z+26$$

So, now, can you find a factor $(z+a)$ that divides that to produce a quadratic?

vis: find $a,b,c$ so $(z+a)(z^2+bz+c) \\ = z^3 +(a+b)z^2+ (ab+c) z+ ac \\ = z^3-2 z^2+5 z+26$

Comment: Are you surr about $5z$?

Comment: @user246608 Yes.

Answer (score 0):

it can be factorized into $$(z+2) \left(z^2-4 z+13\right) \left(z^2-2 z+2\right)$$